# Why XGboost does not work on small dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

Here I am using Xgboost for classification for a simple small dataset, when x = 0 then y = 1 elif x = 1 then y = 0. Then I use the xgb.XGBClassifier() but the resulting probability is just 0.5. I wonder why this happens. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's too few different samples so XGBoost is unable to split the trees properly (you can check the actual trees using `clf.get_booster().get_dump()`). Reducing the `min_child_weight` hyperparameter (e.g. `clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(min_child_weight=0.5)`) should get you some traction.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answering. It is really an important hyper-parameter